# Как продолжить действия после рестарта сервера

Tags: java, веб-программирование

Клиент-серверное приложение написанное на Java. Выполняются какие-то действия (цепочки методов) на сервере, затем сервер падает. Есть ли какие-то средства, чтобы после рестарта сервера продолжалось выполнение прерванных действий? То есть, чтобы восстановились данные до падения сервера, и продолжилась работа последующих методов.

Comment: Да, есть - файлы.

Comment: Я имел ввиду автоматическое продолжение выполнения, файлы сами по себе не поймут что им делать

Comment: @iksuy уже высказался, я дополню - логируйте то что делаете в файлы, по этой информации можно будет продолжить выполнение, так например базы данных работают с транзакциями.

Answer (score 4):

Информация о том, в каком месте и в каком состоянии прервалась программа не может висеть в вакууме. Если сервер (железный или серверное приложение) падает, то программа прекращает выполнение и выгружается из памяти. Чтобы восстановить прежнее состояние, нужно его откуда-то взять. Для этого нужно писать необходимую информацию, например на диск, в файлы. Обычно аккуратно анализируется, какой минимальный набор данных нужен, чтобы восстановить выполнение программы с места падения (или с места, близкого к месту падения) и этот набор пишется на диск через определенные интервалы. При старте программы он загружается с диска и в зависимости от загруженных данных программа продолжает выполнение. Так как для каждой программы набор таких данных будет совершенно разный, как и способ его сохранения на диск и чтения с диска в дальнейшем, то даже если и есть автоматические инструменты (я не слыхал о таких, но может кто сообщит), то думаю что их конфигурация будет не слишком проста, и зачастую проще изобрести свой велосипед под конкретный случай.